# How can i receive data stored in azure table to a website?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

I am doing an IoT project. I want to display data i received from the arduino board to a website showing real-time line graphs. i able to connect and store data comming from the arduino board to azure table storage. But i dont know how can i get the data stored in azure table storage to my website.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to query the table storage in order to get the data and display it.

You can do it using REST API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities

or using Linq:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/writing-linq-queries-against-the-table-service

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Azure Websites, I will assume you are using some flavor of Asp.Net for your web application.  You can pull data from Table Storage using the Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table SDK (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table).  While the name implies it's for CosmosDB, it is also the new package used to access regular Azure Table Storage.  @Thiago rightly says that you can use the REST API, but if you are using Asp.Net/C# for your web app, using the SDK will proably be easier.